# Pyspark, how to calculate poisson distribution using udf?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
df_schema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("col1", FloatType(), True),\
                             StructField("col2", FloatType(), True)])
df_data = [('2020-08-01',0.09,0.8),\
                 ('2020-08-02',0.0483,0.8)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(df_data)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_data, df_schema)
df = df.withColumn("date",to_date("date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df.show() 

+----------+------+----+
|      date|  col1|col2|
+----------+------+----+
|2020-08-01|  0.09| 0.8|
|2020-08-02|0.0483| 0.8|
+----------+------+----+
```

And I want to calculate Poisson CDF using col1 and col2.

we can easily use from scipy.stats import poisson in pandas dataframe but I don't know how to deal with pyspark.

prob = poisson.cdf(x, mu) where x= col1 , and mu = col2 in our case.

ATTEMPT 1 :

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,col
def poisson_calc(a,b):
    return poisson.cdf(a,b,axis=1)

poisson_calc = udf(poisson_calc, FloatType())

df_new = df.select(
  poisson_calc(col('col1'),col('col2')).alias("want") )

df_new.show()
```

Got me an error :TypeError: _parse_args() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some issues with your attempt.

- You named the `udf` the same as the underlying function. Surprisingly this actually isn't a problem per se but I would avoid it.
- There's no `axis` keyword argument to `scipy.stats.poisson.cdf`
- You'll have to explicitly convert the output to `float` or you'll run into [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984775/spark-errorexpected-zero-arguments-for-construction-of-classdict-for-numpy-cor)

Fixing that all up, the following should work:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,col

def poisson_calc(a,b):
    return float(poisson.cdf(a,b))

poisson_calc_udf = udf(poisson_calc, FloatType())

df_new = df.select(
  poisson_calc_udf(col('col1'),col('col2')).alias("want") 
)

df_new.show()
#+----------+
#|      want|
#+----------+
#|0.44932896|
#|0.44932896|
#+----------+
```

Comment: Hi pault, I'm using your udf approach to do poisson calculation. and I think it takes long time to process since I have over millions of data. is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: @dakjdlajsl you can try to rewrite the function using native spark to avoid the `udf`, but I don't know how hard that is (if it's even possible). If you're okay with an approximate solution, an alternative would be to load a poisson distribution table and do a join instead of the exact CDF calculation.