# How to calculate daily basis in pyspark dataframe (time series)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

So I have a dataframe and I want to calculation some quantity let's say in daily basis..let's say we have 10 columns col1,col2,col3,col4... coln which each columns are dependent on value `col1`, col2, col3 , col4.. and so on and the date resets based on the `id`..

```
    +--------+----+----              +----+
        date |col1|id  |col2|.    .  |coln
    +--------+----+----              +----+
    2020-08-01| 0|  M1 |   .    .   .    3|
    2020-08-02| 4|  M1 |                10|
    2020-08-03| 3|  M1 |   .     .   .  9 |
    2020-08-04| 2|  M1 |    .   .    .  8 |
    2020-08-05| 1|  M1 |   .   .     .  7 |
    2020-08-06| 0|  M1 |   .    .   .   0 |
    2020-08-01| 0|  M2 |   .   .     .  0 |
    2020-08-02| 0|  M2 |    .   .   . . 1 |
    2020-08-03| 0|  M2 |    .   .  . .  2 |
   +---------+----+----+-----------------+
```

Let's say we execute this dataframe, there could be alot more columns in this df...
So to make this clear, let's say today's date is 2020-08-01. and we do some calculation and we got some output at coln let's say `coln =3` at 2020-08-01, and I want to coln == col1 at 2020-08-02 which is col1 ==3 and carry on the calculation at 2020-08-02 and so on... so example of df looks like this below

```
    +--------+----+----              +----+
        date |col1|id  |col2|.    .  |coln
    +--------+----+----              +----+
    2020-08-01| 0|  M1 |   .    .   .    3|
    2020-08-02| 3|  M1 |                10|
    2020-08-03|10|  M1 |   .     .   .  9 |
    2020-08-04| 9|  M1 |    .   .    .  8 |
    2020-08-05| 8|  M1 |   .   .     .  7 |
    2020-08-06| 7|  M1 |   .    .   .   0 |
    2020-08-01| 0|  M2 |   .   .     .  1 |
    2020-08-02| 1|  M2 |    .   .   . . 2 |
    2020-08-03| 2|  M2 |    .   .  . .  0 |
   +---------+----+----+-----------------+
```

It would be great if you guys can give me an example how this can be done in pyspark..

**example:** let's say `col3 = col1+ col2` and initally, let's say col1 is all 0.

```
df1_schema = StructType([StructField("Date", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),\
                             StructField("id", StringType(), True),\
                       StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True),\
                       StructField("col3", IntegerType(), True),\
                        StructField("coln", IntegerType(), True)])
df_data = [('2020-08-01',0,'M1',3,3,2),('2020-08-02',0,'M1',2,3,1),\
           ('2020-08-03',0,'M1',3,3,3),('2020-08-04',0,'M1',3,3,1),\
            ('2020-08-01',0,'M2',1,3,1),('2020-08-02',0,'M2',-1,3,2)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(df_data)
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_data, df1_schema)
df1 = df1.withColumn("Date",to_date("Date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df1.show()

+----------+----+---+----+----+----+
|      Date|col1| id|col2|col3|coln|
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+
|2020-08-01|   0| M1|   3|   3|   2|
|2020-08-02|   0| M1|   2|   3|   1|
|2020-08-03|   0| M1|   3|   3|   3|
|2020-08-04|   0| M1|   3|   3|   1|
|2020-08-01|   0| M2|   1|   3|   1|
|2020-08-02|   0| M2|  -1|   3|   2|
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+
```

So Let's focus on `2020-08-01` which is the beginning, and what we want is col1+col2 which is 3 = col3. and after nth calculation that is dependent on col3.. col4... col5.. let's say we got to some number coln= 3. after that calculation is done, we want at `2020-08-02`, that coln=3 should be at col1
so it's a dynamically changing after 2020-08-01 calculation is complete

[image]

so my desired df would look like this

```
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+
|      Date|col1| id|col2|col3|coln|
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+
|2020-08-01|   0| M1|   3|   3|   2|
|2020-08-02|   2| M1|   2|   5|   1|
|2020-08-03|   1| M1|   3|   4|   3|
|2020-08-04|   3| M1|   3|   6|   1|
|2020-08-01|   1| M2|   1|   4|   1|
|2020-08-02|   1| M2|  -1|   0|   2|
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
df1_schema = StructType([StructField("Date", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),\
                             StructField("id", StringType(), True),\
                       StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True),\
                       StructField("col3", IntegerType(), True),\
                       StructField("col4", IntegerType(), True),\
                        StructField("coln", IntegerType(), True)])
df_data = [('2020-08-01',0,'M1',3,3,2,2),('2020-08-02',0,'M1',2,3,0,1),\
           ('2020-08-03',0,'M1',3,3,2,3),('2020-08-04',0,'M1',3,3,2,1),\
            ('2020-08-01',0,'M2',1,3,3,1),('2020-08-02',0,'M2',-1,3,1,2)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(df_data)
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_data, df1_schema)
df1 = df1.withColumn("Date",to_date("Date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df1.show()
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+----+
|      Date|col1| id|col2|col3|col4|coln|
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+----+
|2020-08-01|   0| M1|   3|   3|   2|   2|
|2020-08-02|   0| M1|   2|   3|   0|   1|
|2020-08-03|   0| M1|   3|   3|   2|   3|
|2020-08-04|   0| M1|   3|   3|   2|   1|
|2020-08-01|   0| M2|   1|   3|   3|   1|
|2020-08-02|   0| M2|  -1|   3|   1|   2|
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+----+
```

so let's say coln = col4 - col2 then

```
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+----+
|      Date|col1| id|col2|col3|col4|coln|
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+----+
|2020-08-01|   0| M1|   3|   3|   2|  -1|
|2020-08-02|  -1| M1|   2|   1|   0|  -2|
|2020-08-03|  -2| M1|   3|   1|   2|  -1|
|2020-08-04|  -1| M1|   3|   2|   2|  -1|
|2020-08-01|   0| M2|   1|   1|   3|   2|
|2020-08-02|   2| M2|  -1|   1|   1|   2|
+----------+----+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: from your diagram for id=M1, it looks you just need a Window funcion to calculate col1 from lag('coln'), and then calculate col3: for example let set `w1 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('Date')`, then do `df1.withColumn('col1', F.coalesce(F.lag('coln').over(w1),F.col('col1'))).withColumn('col3', F.col('col1') + F.col('col2')).show()`. but this does not match your desired df, which one is correct?

Comment: ah yes yours are correct. the starting date 2020-08-01 at col1 should be 0

Comment: how about values in col3?

Comment: yes you are correct. but when we are calculating 2020-08-01, the value of coln at 2020-08-02 would be blank/unknown because it did not do the calculation yet. you know what i mean? so let's say I have a script. so at line 50 that does the calculation of col3. and after all the col4,col5,col6 calculation let's say at line 1000, we have calculation for coln. I want to bring that coln value to col1 again like going back to the start and do the calculation for 2020-08-02 and so on.

Comment: is that even possible?

Comment: so you want to use the updated value of `coln` on `2020-08-01` to calculate the `col1` on `2020-08-02`? if so, it's possible to handle this using aggregate function, if you can add an example, for example coln = `col2 - col4` etc and update your diagram for desired result. you might have to pack related calculations all in one function though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222333/discussion-between-hellotherebj-and-jxc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one type of questions you can handle with SparkSQL builtin function [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) (require **Spark 2.4+**), below outlines the basic idea:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sort_array, collect_list, struct, to_date

cols = ['Date', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'coln']

df_new = df1.groupby('id') \
    .agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct(*cols))).alias('dta')) \
    .selectExpr("id", """  
      inline( 
        aggregate( 
          /* expr: iterate through the array `dta` from the 2nd to the last items*/
          slice(dta,2,size(dta)-1), 
          /* start: AKA. the zero value which is an array of structs 
           * with a single element dta[0]
           */
          array(dta[0]), 
          /* merge: do the calculations */
          (acc, x) ->   
            concat(acc, array(named_struct( 
              'Date', x.Date, 
              'col1', element_at(acc, -1).coln, 
              'col2', x.col2, 
              'col3', element_at(acc, -1).col3 + x.col2, 
              'coln', x.col3 - x.col2 
            )))  
         )    
       )    
   """)
```

**Output:**

```
df_new.show()
+---+----------+----+----+----+----+ 
| id|      Date|col1|col2|col3|coln|
+---+----------+----+----+----+----+
| M1|2020-08-01|   0|   3|   3|   2|
| M1|2020-08-02|   2|   2|   5|   1|
| M1|2020-08-03|   1|   3|   8|   0|
| M1|2020-08-04|   0|   3|  11|   0|
| M2|2020-08-01|   0|   1|   3|   1|
| M2|2020-08-02|   1|  -1|   2|   4|
+---+----------+----+----+----+----+
```

**Where:**

1. we groupby rows for the same `id` and sort them by `Date`, name the resulting array of structs as `dta`
2. in the aggregate function, we initialize `acc` with an array of structs `array(dta[0])` and then iterate through the array `dta` from the 2nd item to the last item using [slice](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#slice) function
3. in the `merge` part of the aggregate function, you can use `x.col1`, `x.coln` etc to refer to values on the same Date and use `element_at(acc, -1).col1`, `element_at(acc, -1).coln` etc to refer the values from the previous Date.
4. in the merge function, we use `concat(acc, array(...))` to append a new element to the array of structs `acc`
5. use [inline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) function to explode the above array of structs `acc`
6. this assumed Dates are continuous, if missing date exists, you can add some IF conditions. for example to calculate `col3` below:

   ```
   IF(datediff(x.Date, element_at(acc, -1).Date) = 1, element_at(acc, -1).coln, 0) + x.col2
   ```

BTW. I did not use the example `coln = col4 - col2`, using `con3 = col3_prev + col2` instead, I think, is a better example.

Comment: could you have look at this problem jxc? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64177603/how-to-loop-dataframe-in-pyspark

Comment: hi, @hellotherebj, is the new question related to this post, I think you can just use a similar way here but groupby('Date'), sort the collect_list by `id` (desc or asc).

Comment: hi jxc, for this problem, what if I want to lag `col2` (any window functions) and use that to get coln? is it possible to lag in array form in general?

Comment: @hellotherebj, use `element_at(acc, -1).col2` if you want the col2 which is just updated in the previous iteration.

Comment: can we implement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290611/pyspark-how-to-code-complicated-dataframe-calculation this complicated calculation here somehow?

Comment: hi, @hellotherebj. if you are looking to resolve a big time series when the related rows have to be distributed on multiple partitions. there is probably no easy way to handle in Spark. this code is only logically working for a dataset which can be easily loaded into memory. BTW, the first argument of aggregate function could be `slice(dta,2,size(dta))`, just skip the `minus 1` to the length of the slice which yield ERROR for EMPTY arrays.

Comment: Thank you jxc, all I want is build a logic like this one that does it in recursive, like referring coln = col1 for tomorrow.. and all other columns are depended on that col1 value..  what would be some options?, one option is to change the df to the array (pandas df) ??.. any advice?   but I am not sure how to implement it..