# Pyspark: how to round up or down (round to the nearest)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a **df** that looks like this

```
TEST_schema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), True),\
                          StructField("col1", FloatType(), True),\
                          ])
TEST_data = [('2020-08-01',1.22),('2020-08-02',1.15),('2020-08-03',5.4),('2020-08-04',2.6),('2020-08-05',3.5),\
             ('2020-08-06',2.2),('2020-08-07',2.7),('2020-08-08',-1.6),('2020-08-09',1.3)]
rdd3 = sc.parallelize(TEST_data)
TEST_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(TEST_data, TEST_schema)
TEST_df = TEST_df.withColumn("date",to_date("date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
TEST_df.show() 

+----------+-----+
|      date|col1 |
+----------+-----+
|2020-08-01| 1.22|
|2020-08-02| 1.15|
|2020-08-03| 5.4 |
|2020-08-04| 2.6 |
|2020-08-05| 3.5 |
|2020-08-06| 2.2 |
|2020-08-07| 2.7 |
|2020-08-08|-1.6 |
|2020-08-09| 1.3 |
+----------+-----+
```

Logic : round **col1** to the nearest and return as **integer** , and **max( rounded value , 0)**

the resulted df looks like this:

```
+----------+----+----+
|      date|col1|want|
+----------+----+----+
|2020-08-01| 1.2|   1|
|2020-08-02| 1.1|   1|
|2020-08-03| 5.4|   5|
|2020-08-04| 2.6|   3|
|2020-08-05| 3.5|   4|
|2020-08-06| 2.2|   2|
|2020-08-07| 2.7|   3|
|2020-08-08|-1.6|   0|
|2020-08-09| 1.3|   1|
+----------+----+----+
```

Comment: check `TEST_df.selectExpr("*", "greatest(int(round(col1,0)),0) as want").show()`

Comment: what if I want to return just the nearest? not considering the max

Comment: ah that's just round(col1,0) nvm :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the duplicated question that gives you all.

```
data = [('2020-08-01',1.22),('2020-08-02',1.15),('2020-08-03',5.4),('2020-08-04',2.6),('2020-08-05',3.5),('2020-08-06',2.2),('2020-08-07',2.7),('2020-08-08',-1.6),('2020-08-09',1.3)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['date', 'col1'])

df.withColumn('want', expr('ROUND(col1, 0)').cast('int')).show() 

+----------+----+----+
|      date|col1|want|
+----------+----+----+
|2020-08-01|1.22|   1|
|2020-08-02|1.15|   1|
|2020-08-03| 5.4|   5|
|2020-08-04| 2.6|   3|
|2020-08-05| 3.5|   4|
|2020-08-06| 2.2|   2|
|2020-08-07| 2.7|   3|
|2020-08-08|-1.6|  -2|
|2020-08-09| 1.3|   1|
+----------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

First, here i am checking whether it's lessthan zero or not. Here we are using
when method in pyspark functions, first we check whether the value in the column
is lessthan zero, if it is will make it to zero, otherwise we take the actual value in the column then cast to int
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

```
TEST_df.withColumn("want", F.bround(F.when(TEST_df["col1"] < 0, 0).otherwise(TEST_df["col1"])).cast("int")).show()
+----------+----+----+
|      date|col1|want|
+----------+----+----+
|2020-08-01|1.22|   1|
|2020-08-02|1.15|   1|
|2020-08-03| 5.4|   5|
|2020-08-04| 2.6|   3|
|2020-08-05| 3.5|   4|
|2020-08-06| 2.2|   2|
|2020-08-07| 2.7|   3|
|2020-08-08|-1.6|   0|
|2020-08-09| 1.3|   1|
+----------+----+----+
```