# Pyspark: how to solve complicated dataframe logic plus join

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two data frames to work on, the first one looks like this the following **df1**

```
df1_schema = StructType([StructField("Date", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("store_id", StringType(), True),\
                             StructField("warehouse_id", StringType(), True),\
                      StructField("class_id", StringType(), True) ,\
                       StructField("total_time", IntegerType(), True) ])
df_data = [('2020-08-01','110','1','11010',3),('2020-08-02','110','1','11010',2),\
           ('2020-08-03','110','1','11010',3),('2020-08-04','110','1','11010',3),\
            ('2020-08-05','111','1','11010',1),('2020-08-06','111','1','11010',-1)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(df_data)
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_data, df1_schema)
df1 = df1.withColumn("Date",to_date("Date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df1.show()

+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|total_time|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|         3|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|         2|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|         3|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|         3|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|         1|
|2020-08-06|     111|           1|   11010|        -1|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+
```

I calculated something called **arrival_date**

```
#To calculate the arrival_date
#logic : add the Date + total_time so in first row, 2020-08-01 +3 would give me 2020-08-04 
#if total_time is -1 then return blank
df1= df1.withColumn('arrival_date', F.when(col('total_time') != -1, expr("date_add(date, total_time)"))
        .otherwise(''))
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|total_time|arrival_date|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-04|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|         2|  2020-08-04|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-06|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-07|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|         1|  2020-08-06|
|2020-08-06|     111|           1|   11010|        -1|            |
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+
```

and what I want to calculate is this..

```
#to calculate the transit_date
#if arrival_date is same, ex) 2020-08-04 is repeated 2 or more times, then take min("Date") 
#which will be 2020-08-01 otherwise just return the Date ex) 2020-08-07 would just return 2020-08-04
#we need to care about cloth_id too, we have arrival_date = 2020-08-06 repeated 2 times as well but since
#if one of store_id or warehouse_id is different we treat them separately. so at arrival_date = 2020-08-06 at date = 2020-08-03,
##we must return 2020-08-03 
#so we treat them separately when one of (store_id, warehouse_id ) is different. 
#*Note* we dont care about class_id, its not effective.
#if arrival_date = blank then leave it as blank..
#so our df would look something like this.
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|total_time|arrival_date|transit_date|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-04|  2020-08-01|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|         2|  2020-08-04|  2020-08-01|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-06|  2020-08-03|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-07|  2020-08-04|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|         1|  2020-08-06|  2020-08-05|
|2020-08-06|     111|           1|   11010|        -1|            |            |
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
```

Next, I have **df2** looks like the following..

```
#we have another dataframe call it df2

df2_schema = StructType([StructField("Date", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("store_id", StringType(), True),\
                             StructField("warehouse_id", StringType(), True),\
                             StructField("cloth_id", StringType(), True),\
                      StructField("class_id", StringType(), True) ,\
                       StructField("type", StringType(), True),\
                        StructField("quantity", IntegerType(), True)])
df_data = [('2020-08-01','110','1','M_1','11010','R',5),('2020-08-01','110','1','M_1','11010','R',2),\
           ('2020-08-02','110','1','M_1','11010','C',3),('2020-08-03','110','1','M_1','11010','R',1),\
            ('2020-08-04','110','1','M_1','11010','R',3),('2020-08-05','111','1','M_2','11010','R',5)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(df_data)
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_data, df2_schema)
df2 = df2.withColumn("Date",to_date("Date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df2.show()

+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+--------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|cloth_id|class_id|type|quantity|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+--------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|   R|       5|
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|   R|       2|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|   C|       3|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|   R|       1|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|   R|       3|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|     M_2|   11010|   R|       5|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+--------+
```

and I calculated **quantity2**, this is just sum of quantity where type=R

```
df2 =df2.groupBy('Date','store_id','warehouse_id','cloth_id','class_id')\
      .agg( F.sum(F.when(col('type')=='R', col('quantity'))\
      .otherwise(col('quantity'))).alias('quantity2')).orderBy('Date')
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|cloth_id|class_id|quantity2|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        7|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        3|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        1|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        3|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|     M_2|   11010|        5|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Now I have df1, and df2. I want to join such that It will look something like this...
I tried something like this

```
df4 = df1.select('store_id','warehouse_id','class_id','arrival_date','transit_date')
df4= df4.filter(" transit_date != '' ")

df4=df4.withColumnRenamed('arrival_date', 'date')

df3 = df2.join(df1, on=['Date','store_id','warehouse_id','class_id'],how='inner').orderBy('Date')
df5 = df3.join(df4, on=['Date','store_id','warehouse_id','class_id'], how='left').orderBy('Date')
```

but I dont think this is the correct approach.... the result df should look like below..

```
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|cloth_id|quantity2|total_time|arrival_date|transit_date|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        7|         3|  2020-08-04|        null|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        3|         2|  2020-08-04|        null|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        1|         3|  2020-08-06|        null|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        3|         3|  2020-08-07|  2020-08-01|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|     M_2|        5|         1|  2020-08-06|        null|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

note that the transit_date went to where `Date = arrival_date` of course the null is replaced by blank.

LASTLY, if today is 2020-08-04, then look at where arrival_date == 2020-08-04 and sum up the quantity and place it at today. so.... It will look like this... where the store_id = 111, it will have separate date. not shown here.. so logic needs to make sense when store_id = 111 as well.. i've just shown the example where store_id = 110
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what is your desired dataframe.

Comment: I edited the desired dataframe for "want" column. your transit_date makes sense to me.. thank you..

Comment: in the final dataframe, how is the last Row with 'Date=2020-08-06, cloth_id=M_1, quantity2=3' from? is this entry missing from the example df2?

Comment: i manually created for exmaple purposes.

Comment: just wanted to show that quantity2 =1 where i boxed goes to Date=2020-08-06

Comment: @jxc do you want more explanation? or you good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding about your question and where you already have with the following `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1.orderBy('Date').show()                                           df2.orderBy('Date').show()
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+  +----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|total_time|arrival_date|  |      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|cloth_id|class_id|quantity2|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+  +----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-04|  |2020-08-01|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        7|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|         2|  2020-08-04|  |2020-08-02|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        3|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-06|  |2020-08-03|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        1|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-07|  |2020-08-04|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        3|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|         1|  2020-08-06|  |2020-08-05|     111|           1|     M_2|   11010|        5|
|2020-08-06|     111|           1|   11010|        -1|            |  +----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+
```

you can try the following 5 steps:

**Step-1:** Set up the list of column names `grp_cols` for join:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
grp_cols = ["Date", "store_id", "warehouse_id", "class_id"]
```

**Step-2:** create df3 containing `transit_date` which is the min Date on each combination of `arrival_date`, `store_id`, `warehouse_id` and `class_id`:

```
df3 = df1.filter('total_time != -1') \
    .groupby("arrival_date", "store_id", "warehouse_id", "class_id") \
    .agg(F.min('Date').alias('transit_date')) \
    .withColumnRenamed("arrival_date", "Date")

df3.orderBy('Date').show()
+----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|transit_date|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|  2020-08-01|
|2020-08-06|     111|           1|   11010|  2020-08-05|
|2020-08-06|     110|           1|   11010|  2020-08-03|
|2020-08-07|     110|           1|   11010|  2020-08-04|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
```

**Step-3:** set up df4 by join df2 with df1 and left join df3 using grp_cols, persist df4

```
df4 = df2.join(df1, grp_cols).join(df3, grp_cols, "left") \
    .withColumn('transit_date', F.when(F.col('total_time') != -1, F.col("transit_date")).otherwise('')) \
    .persist()
_ = df4.count()
df4.orderBy('Date').show()
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|cloth_id|quantity2|total_time|arrival_date|transit_date|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        7|         3|  2020-08-04|        null|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        3|         2|  2020-08-04|        null|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        1|         3|  2020-08-06|        null|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        3|         3|  2020-08-07|  2020-08-01|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|     M_2|        5|         1|  2020-08-06|        null|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

**Step-4:** calculate `sum(quantity2) as want` from df4 for each `arrival_date` + `store_id` + `warehouse_id` + `class_id` + `cloth_id`

```
df5 = df4 \
    .groupby("arrival_date", "store_id", "warehouse_id", "class_id", "cloth_id") \
    .agg(F.sum("quantity2").alias("want")) \
    .withColumnRenamed("arrival_date", "Date")
df5.orderBy('Date').show()
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|cloth_id|want|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|  10|
|2020-08-06|     111|           1|   11010|     M_2|   5|
|2020-08-06|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|   1|
|2020-08-07|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|   3|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+----+
```

**Step-5:** create the final dataframe by left join df4 with df5

```
df_new = df4.join(df5, grp_cols+["cloth_id"], "left").fillna(0, subset=['want'])
df_new.orderBy("Date").show()
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+----+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|cloth_id|quantity2|total_time|arrival_date|transit_date|want|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+----+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        7|         3|  2020-08-04|        null|   0|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        3|         2|  2020-08-04|        null|   0|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        1|         3|  2020-08-06|        null|   0|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|     M_1|        3|         3|  2020-08-07|  2020-08-01|  10|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|     M_2|        5|         1|  2020-08-06|        null|   0|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+----+
df4.unpersist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is for the df1,

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import builtins as p

df1_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('Date',         StringType(),  True),
        StructField('store_id',     StringType(),  True),
        StructField('warehouse_id', StringType(),  True),
        StructField('class_id',     StringType(),  True),
        StructField('total_time',   IntegerType(), True)
    ]
)

df1_data = [
    ('2020-08-01','110','1','11010',3),
    ('2020-08-02','110','1','11010',2),
    ('2020-08-03','110','1','11010',3),
    ('2020-08-04','110','1','11010',3),
    ('2020-08-05','111','1','11010',1),
    ('2020-08-06','111','1','11010',-1)
]


df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1_data, df1_schema)
df1 = df1.withColumn('Date', to_date('Date'))

df1 = df1.withColumn('arrival_date', when(col('total_time') != -1, expr("date_add(date, total_time)")).otherwise(''))

w = Window.partitionBy('arrival_date', 'store_id', 'warehouse_id').orderBy('Date')
df1 = df1.withColumn('transit_date', when(col('total_time') != -1, first('Date').over(w)).otherwise('')).orderBy('Date')

df1.show()

+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|total_time|arrival_date|transit_date|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-04|  2020-08-01|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|         2|  2020-08-04|  2020-08-01|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-06|  2020-08-03|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|         3|  2020-08-07|  2020-08-04|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|         1|  2020-08-06|  2020-08-05|
|2020-08-06|     111|           1|   11010|        -1|            |            |
+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
```

and df2 as you did,

```
df2_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('Date',         StringType(),  True),
        StructField('store_id',     StringType(),  True),
        StructField('warehouse_id', StringType(),  True),
        StructField('cloth_id',     StringType(),  True),
        StructField('class_id',     StringType(),  True),
        StructField('type',         StringType(),  True),
        StructField('quantity',     IntegerType(), True)
    ]
)

df2_data = [
    ('2020-08-01','110','1','M_1','11010','R',5),
    ('2020-08-01','110','1','M_1','11010','R',2),
    ('2020-08-02','110','1','M_1','11010','C',3),
    ('2020-08-03','110','1','M_1','11010','R',1),
    ('2020-08-04','110','1','M_1','11010','R',3),
    ('2020-08-05','111','1','M_2','11010','R',5)
]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2_data, df2_schema)
df2 = df2.withColumn('Date', to_date('Date'))

df2 = df2.groupBy('Date', 'store_id', 'warehouse_id', 'cloth_id', 'class_id') \
        .agg(
            sum(
                when(col('type') == 'R', col('quantity')).otherwise(0)
            ).alias('quantity2')
        ).orderBy('Date')

df2.show()

+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|cloth_id|class_id|quantity2|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        7|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        0|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        1|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|     M_1|   11010|        3|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|     M_2|   11010|        5|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+---------+
```

and finally the join result.

```
df3 = df1.filter('total_time != -1') \
  .join(df2, on=['Date', 'store_id', 'warehouse_id', 'class_id'], how='left') \
  .drop('Date', 'total_time', 'cloth_id') \
  .withColumnRenamed('arrival_date', 'Date')

df4 = df1.drop('transit_date') \
  .join(df3, on=['Date', 'store_id', 'warehouse_id', 'class_id'], how='left') \
  .groupBy('Date', 'store_id', 'warehouse_id', 'class_id', 'arrival_date', 'transit_date') \
  .agg(sum('quantity2').alias('want')) \
  .orderBy('Date')

df4.show()

+----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+------------+----+
|      Date|store_id|warehouse_id|class_id|arrival_date|transit_date|want|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+------------+----+
|2020-08-01|     110|           1|   11010|  2020-08-04|        null|null|
|2020-08-02|     110|           1|   11010|  2020-08-04|        null|null|
|2020-08-03|     110|           1|   11010|  2020-08-06|        null|null|
|2020-08-04|     110|           1|   11010|  2020-08-07|  2020-08-01|   7|
|2020-08-05|     111|           1|   11010|  2020-08-06|        null|null|
|2020-08-06|     111|           1|   11010|            |  2020-08-05|   5|
+----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+------------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you, Lamanus, your final join 2020-08-04 seems like duplicate? I edited the final goal, with new image.. so you see arrival_date = 2020-08-04 is repeated at 2020-08-01 and 2020-08-02, we want to sum the quantity2 which is 7+0 =7 and place that quantity at Date = 2020-08-04

Comment: let me know if you are still struggling regards to the final output